# iOS app Crashes after signing and installing on device: DYLD, dependent dylib '@rpath/LegacyDatabase.framework/LegacyDatabase' not found

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, telegram

After getting an archived export of my app and installing it on device, app crashes and **I get this error on device `analytics` data:**

```
Termination Description: DYLD, dependent dylib 
  '@rpath/LegacyDatabase.framework/LegacyDatabase' not found for 
    '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/[APP_BUNDLE]/[APP_NAME].app/PlugIns/Widget.appex/Widget', tried but didn't find: 
    '@rpath/LegacyDatabase.framework/LegacyDatabase' 
    '/System/Library/Frameworks/LegacyDatabase.framework/LegacyDatabase'
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to setup LegacyDatabase dependency. 
Check build phases.
LegacyDatabase should be inside `Dependencies` and `Link Binary with Libraries`

Then check Build Settings
`framework search paths` should point to location fo LegacyDatabase